# Can canned food (like tuna) be refridgerated for months then put back in the pantry?

Tags: refrigerator, canning, tuna

I forgot about the tuna I left in the fridge.

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about putting a still sealed can into the refrigerator and then after a few months moving it into the place where you normally store canned foods. All this without opening the can... Yes that is fine. As long as the seal of the can isn't compromised, the contents of the can won't spoil.

Comment: However, if the can is open it should be discarded.